# VBA Code is not copying and pasting in the correct workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code shown below that allows me to save a copy of a workbook as an XLSX file with a file name that is different each time the code is ran. The code works to save the file correctly with the correct name. However, when it comes to the part where it should be copying and pasting the data in the new file as values it doesn't do it to the new file, only the original. My goal is to have a copy of the original file that does not have any macros or queries in it.

Can someone help create a way for the code to realize that it needs to do the copy and pasting in the new file?

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim PathName As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim AWorkbook As String
AWorkbook = "Operational Dashboard Worksheet"
PathName = Sheet4.Range("B7").Value
FileName = Sheet4.Range("B5").Value

Workbooks(AWorkbook).Save
Workbooks(AWorkbook).Sheets(Array("Dashboard", "Extra Details", "Worksheet", "Occupancy", "Shrinkage", _
    "SL Impact", "VBA Codes")).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs PathName & FileName & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51

Workbooks(FileName).Activate
Sheet2.Range("Q:AD").Copy
Workbooks(FileName).Activate
Sheet2.Range("Q:AD").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Workbooks(FileName).Activate
Sheet3.Range("B:AI").Copy
Workbooks(FileName).Activate
Sheet3.Range("B:AI").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Workbooks(FileName).Activate
Sheet7.Range("N:AQ").Copy
Workbooks(FileName).Activate
Sheet7.Range("N:AQ").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Workbooks(FileName).Activate
Sheet5.Range("A:G").Copy
Workbooks(FileName).Activate
Sheet5.Range("A:G").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Workbooks(FileName).Activate
Sheet5.Range("AB:AS").Copy
Workbooks(FileName).Activate
Sheet5.Range("AB:AS").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Workbooks(FileName).Activate
Sheet5.Range("AX:CQ").Copy
Workbooks(FileName).Activate
Sheet5.Range("AX:CQ").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Workbooks(AWorkbook).Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
```

End Sub

Comment: Goto to file, save as, and save as an .xlsx, it will remove all your macros.
Run macro recorder to get the basic macro, change as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Worksheet.Activate` works, but it can get confusing swapping back and forth. Creating a reference to your Source and Destination Workbooks and sheets makes it easier (imo) to keep track of things, and it can also speed things up a little since you're just dealing with the data and not the gui.

```
' eg
Dim SourceBook As Wokbook
Set SourceBook = ThisWorkbook
```

I think your problem could be using `SheetN.Range` in your code to copy the data. `SheetN` probably looks to `ThisWorkbook` and not `ActiveWorkbook` for the data. So you are doing stuff to your original workbook.

The sheet index used in my code might not match up with your original code. You can replace the Index `Sheets(Index)` with the name of the sheet your trying to copy data on.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim PathName As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim AWorkbook As String
AWorkbook = "Operational Dashboard Worksheet"
PathName = Sheet4.Range("B7").Value
FileName = Sheet4.Range("B5").Value

Workbooks(AWorkbook).Save
Workbooks(AWorkbook).Sheets(Array("Dashboard", "Extra Details", "Worksheet", "Occupancy", "Shrinkage", _
    "SL Impact", "VBA Codes")).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs PathName & FileName & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51

Dim Book As Workbook
Set Book = Workbooks(FileName)

Book.Sheets(2).Range("Q:AD").Copy
Book.Sheets(2).Range("Q:AD").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Book.Sheets(3).Range("B:AI").Copy
Book.Sheets(3).Range("B:AI").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Book.Sheets(7).Range("N:AQ").Copy
Book.Sheets(7).Range("N:AQ").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Book.Sheets(5).Range("A:G").Copy
Book.Sheets(5).Range("A:G").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Book.Sheets(5).Range("AB:AS").Copy
Book.Sheets(5).Range("AB:AS").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Book.Sheets(5).Range("AX:CQ").Copy
Book.Sheets(5).Range("AX:CQ").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Book.Save

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

**Update**

I don't really use the `SheetN` (code name) so my understanding was not quite right. It's the name defined in the VBA editor for the sheet and when used does directly reference the sheet. (you can edit them in the VBA editor too so Sheet1->Dashboard?)[image: code name]

After testing it seems that when you use `Workbooks(..).Worksheets(...).Copy` like in your code and mine too it also copies those name to the new workbook. This is good, but you cant directly reference code names from another workbook.
Below is a modified version of my code that indirectly references them using some code I found. (not tested and not very pretty)

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim PathName As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim AWorkbook As String
AWorkbook = "Operational Dashboard Worksheet"
PathName = Sheet4.Range("B7").Value
FileName = Sheet4.Range("B5").Value


Workbooks(AWorkbook).Save
Workbooks(AWorkbook).Sheets(Array("Dashboard", "Extra Details", "Worksheet", "Occupancy", "Shrinkage", _
    "SL Impact", "VBA Codes")).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs PathName & FileName & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51

Dim Book As Workbook
Set Book = Workbooks(FileName)

Dim Sheet2N As Worksheet
Set Sheet2N = GetWsFromCodeName(Book, "Sheet2")
Dim Sheet3N As Worksheet
Set Sheet3N = GetWsFromCodeName(Book, "Sheet3")
Dim Sheet5N As Worksheet
Set Sheet5N = GetWsFromCodeName(Book, "Sheet4")
Dim Sheet7N As Worksheet
Set Sheet7N = GetWsFromCodeName(Book, "Sheet7")

Sheet2N.Range("Q:AD").Copy
Sheet2N.Range("Q:AD").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Sheet3N.Range("B:AI").Copy
Sheet3N.Range("B:AI").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Sheet7N.Range("N:AQ").Copy
Sheet7N.Range("N:AQ").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Sheet5N.Range("A:G").Copy
Sheet5N.Range("A:G").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Sheet5N.Range("AB:AS").Copy
Sheet5N.Range("AB:AS").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Sheet5N.Range("AX:CQ").Copy
Sheet5N.Range("AX:CQ").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Book.Save

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub

'http://yoursumbuddy.com/using-worksheet-codenames-in-other-workbooks/
Function GetWsFromCodeName(wb As Workbook, CodeName As String) As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    If ws.CodeName = CodeName Then
        Set GetWsFromCodeName = ws
        Exit For
    End If
Next ws
End Function
```

Comment: I think you are right that by using SheetN.Range it was causing problems. I was trying to use the CodeNames of the sheets rather than the names used in Sheets(N). Is there a way I can get around having to use Sheets(N) so that I can use SheetN? I am trying to keep it so that if a worksheet name changes, it won't affect the code.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't fully tested this but when I try to execute `Workbooks("Stores").Activate` in Immediate Pane when I know that Stores is open throws a Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range error.

If I add the file extension `Workbooks("Stores.xlsx").Activate` it works fine and executing `?ActiveWorkbook.Name` returns `Stores.xlsx`.

So your:

```
Workbooks(FileName).Activate
```

Should be:

```
Workbooks(FileName & ".xlsx").Activate
```

Or you could add the extension when defining your FileName:

```
FileName = Sheet4.Range("B5").Value & "xlsx"
```

That said, you rarely need to `Activate` anything in VBA.  For example:

```
Workbooks(FileName).Activate
Sheet2.Range("Q:AD").Copy
Workbooks(FileName).Activate
Sheet2.Range("Q:AD").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

could be replaced with:

```
Workbooks(FileName).Sheet2.Range("Q:AD").Copy
Workbooks(FileName).Sheet2.Range("Q:AD").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it still was a problem. I believe it was because of the SheetN.Range that NickSlash mentioned below. That said, I changed several part of my code so that I don't have to use "Activate". Thank you!